# How to focus React MUI TextField when dialog opens

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have TextField inside Dialog, which I want to focus everytime Dialog is opened. I tried using `inputRef` callback, but TextField doesn't get focused. Adding `autoFocus` prop to TextField also doesn't help.

Minimal example:

```
import { Button, Dialog, DialogContent, TextField } from "@mui/material";
import { useState } from "react";

function ExampleDialog(props: { isOpen: boolean; onClose: () => void }) {
  return (
    <Dialog open={props.isOpen} onClose={props.onClose}>
      <DialogContent>
        <TextField inputRef={(input) => input && input.focus()} fullWidth />
      </DialogContent>
    </Dialog>
  );
}

function App() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        color="success"
        onClick={() => {
          setIsOpen(true);
        }}
      >
        Open dialog
      </Button>

      <ExampleDialog isOpen={isOpen} onClose={() => setIsOpen(false)} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

- `react` version: 18.2.0
- `@mui/material` version: 5.11.16

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you check this https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/33004

Seems like the Strict mode in React 18 breaks that behaviour

Either remove it or add `disableRestoreFocus` prop to the `Dialog` component